# mongoose - get where date ranges overlap

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, orm, nosql

In nodejs with the mongoose ORM im trying to make a query that gets all the booking objects where 'start' and 'end' date overlap with two other dates.

```
let start = req.params.start;
let end = req.params.end;

Booking.find({
    $or: [{userID: userID}, {invites: userID}],
    $or: [{ $and: [{ start: { $gte: start }}, {start: { $lte: end }}],
      $and: [{start: { $lte: start }}, {end: { $gte: start }}]}
    ]}
```

*e1 start > e2 start AND e1 start < e2 end
OR 
e2 start > e1 start AND e2 start < e1 end*

But it dosent work properly. Returns an empty array on dates that overlaps

Answer (score 0):

You have to split the $and statements like this:

```
$or : [{$and:...}, {$and:...}]
```

not like this:

```
$or : [{$and:... , $and:...}]
```

Otherwise, you'll have an $or query with only one option, which is almost impossible to fulfill, since the only case where this condition would be fulfilled is, if start and end are exactly equal to the input values.

Also, you are still missing two out of the four possible cases if you want all events intersecting in any way with the given timeframe:

```
  $and: [{start: { $lte: start }}, {end: { $lte: start }}]}
  $and: [{start: { $gte: start }}, {end: { $gte: start }}]}
```

[image]